# How to show current names collation in MYSQL (PHP)

Tags: mysql

I am testing if my query works and cannot actually do it.

I have this query in my php file.

> SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'

Now I want to do the opposite, something like "SHOW CURRENT COLLATE".
Means I want to know what is NAMES COLLATE SET TO BEFORE MY QUERY AND AFTER MY QUERY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select that info from `information_schema`:

```
SELECT `TABLE_COLLATION` 
       FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` 
       WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = 'yourtablename'
```